# can we reverse proxy for 2 different site on same localhost

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have `httpd.conf` configuration like below,

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ https://mysite1.com/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*)$ https://mysite1.com/$1
```

When I am running httpd and over the browser when I do http://localhost, it's redirects to the landing page of site https://mysite1.com perfectly.

Now on button click over landing page, browser navigates to other site https://my-OTHER-site1.com/oauth2/....

Question, How I can configure reverse proxy for other site https://my-OTHER-site1.com along with my site https://mysite1.com?

I tried below config, but not working, please suggest?

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ https://mysite1.com/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*)$ https://mysite1.com/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ https://my-OTHER-site1.com/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*)$ https://my-OTHER-site1.com/$1
```

**EDIT**

The landing page is https://site1.mydoamin.com and after that it is redirected to the auth site https://site2.mydoamin.com/oauth2/auth?client_id...

```
https://site1.mydoamin.com/
https://site2.mydoamin.com/oauth2/auth?client_id...
```

I tried to differentiate both like below, but no luck, any suggestion please ?

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ https://site1.mydoamin.com/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^/oauth2/(.*)$ https://site2.mydoamin.com/$1
```

Comment: Well, you need different URLs from the point of view of the client. How else should the sites be distinguished?

Comment: And btw, what you implement is a simple proxy, not a redirection. Those are two very different things.

Comment: @arkascha. Thank you for the response. I am new to this tech. I get what you're saying here, question, can redirection is possible in my case?

Comment: Sure it is possible implementing two different proxy rules in a single http host. _If you use different base URLs. Your current pattern matches exactly the same base URL. Which is why obviously only the first or no ruleset will get applied. You need to different matching patterns matching different base URLs. First the exception, the more specialized path, then the more general, default pattern.

Comment: @arkascha. Thanks. I get it what you tries to says here. I tried, but no luck. Please check EDIT section of question and please suggest!

Comment: As said before: first the more specialized exception, then the more general matching rule. Rules are processed from top to bottom.